# Arbitrary Function - Generate return type according to input

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

Given this classes:

```
class Step
case class Publish(p: String) extends Step
case class Receive(p: String) extends Step

class Data
case class Input(p: Int) extends Data
case class Output(p: Int) extends Data

type P = Publish
type R = Receive
type I = Input
type O = Output
```

I would like to have a `method`/`trait`/`class` that takes `Step*` parameters in a `Publish`/`Receive` sequence and return a method that takes `Data` parameters in a sequence of `Input`/`Output`.

For example, for:

```
val flow = Flow {"flow" =>
    (P("1"), R("2"), P("3"), R("4"), R("5"), P("6"), R("7"))
}
```

I should be able to then make the call:

```
flow(I(1), O(2), I(3), O(4), O(5), I(6), O(7))
```

The closest I got to this is defining `Flow` as an object:

```
object Flow {
    def apply[T](f: String => T)(implicit val s: String): T => Unit = f(s) => ()
}
```

which gives me this signature for the above example as `flow: (P, R, P, R, R, P, R) => Unit`

How can I map `P -> I` and `R -> O` in order to make the call on `flow` with Inputs and Outputs, and assure type checking at compile time?

Searching for a solution, I stumbled upon [`shapeless`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) and [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) as frameworks which I think may help me, but I can't really figure it out.

---

After [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566067/arbitrary-function-generate-return-type-according-to-input/32566204#32566204), I rewrote the `Flow` into:

```
object Flow {
    def apply[T <: HList, S <: HList](t: T)
        (implicit mapper : Mapper[IOFlow.type, T]): S => Unit = {
        val s = t.map(IOFlow)
        s => ()
    }
}

object IOFlow extends Poly1 {
    implicit val in = at[P]{ i => makeI(i) }
    implicit val out = at[R]{ r => makeO(r) }

    def makeI(p: P) = Input // so the return type is Input.type
    def makeO(p: R) = Output // and Output.type
}

object Main extends App {

    val initialList = HList(P("1"), R("2"), P("3"), R("4"), R("5"), P("6"), R("7"))
    val flow = Flow(initialList)
}
```

And I'm getting an error for `implicit mapper`, with actually is received at `t.map(IOFLow)`:

```
Error: could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[com.tasegula.scala.shapeless.IOFlow.type,this.Repr]
val flow = Flow(hlist)
               ^
```

So:

1. How can I give an implicit mapper?
2. Is there a way to change the `Flow#apply` method declaration to `apply(t: Step*)`, so the call would be `Flow(P("1"), R("2"), P("3"), R("4"), R("5"), P("6"), R("7"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors, finally got a solution:
Created a wrapper for the `Data` types, so:

```
Publish returns a Wrapper1[Input]
Receive returns a Wrapper1[Output]
```

Also, because I had a sequence of steps, I created a `Wrapper` for each possible number of parameters:

```
case class Wrapper1[T1](s1: String)
case class Wrapper2[T1, T2](s1: String, s2: String)
...
```

Each one of this wrapper has a method with combines it with a `Wrapper1[S]` and returns a `Wrapper(n+1)[T1..Tn, S]`.
Also, each one has a start method that takes n parameters of the given types.

```
case class Wrapper1[T1](s1: String) {
    def +[S](step: W1[S]): W2[T1, S] = W2(s1, step.s1)

    def start(p1: T1) = println("PARAMS: " + List(p1))
}

case class Wrapper2[T1, T2](s1: String, s2: String) {
    def +[S](step: W1[S]): W3[T1, T2, S] = W2(s1, s2, step.s1)

    def start(p1: T1, p2: T2) = println("PARAMS: " + List(p1, p2))
}
```

Now the `IOFlow` becomes an object with an `apply` for each `Wrapper`:

```
object IOFlow {
    def apply[T1](flow: W1[T1]): (T1) => Unit = flow.start
    def apply[T1, T2](flow: W2[T1, T2]): (T1, T2) => Unit = flow.start
    ...
}
```

And the `Main` app:

```
object Main extends App {
    val flow = IOFLow(P("1") + R("2") + P("3") + R("4") + R("5") + P("6") + R("7"))
    flow(I(1), O(2), I(3), O(4), O(5), I(6), O(7))
}
```

So, behind the curtains, this happens:

```
P("1") + R("2") + P("3") + R("4") + R("5") + P("6") + R("7") =>
W1[I]  + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W2[O]  + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W1[O]
```

Then each `+` takes action:

```
W1[I]  + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W2[O]  + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W1[O] =
W2[I, O]        + W1[I]  + W2[O]  + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W1[O] = 
W3[I, O, I]              + W2[O]  + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W1[O] = 
W4[I, O, I, O]                    + W1[O]  + W1[I]  + W1[O] = 
W5[I, O, I, O, O]                          + W1[I]  + W1[O] = 
W6[I, O, I, O, O, I]                                + W1[O] = 
W7[I, O, I, O, O, I, O]
```

so then the call is actually:

```
val flow = IOFlow(W7[I, O, I, O, O, I, O]("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

which means it will be called:

```
apply[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7](flow: W7[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7]): (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7) => Unit = flow.start
```

which means `flow` will be a function that takes 7 paramters: `(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)` and returns an `Unit`. The behaviour of this function is defined in the `Wrapper7#start` method.

Answer (score 2):

How can you do this easily? I would take a look at [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) which can actually do everything you want by defining a Poly:

```
object IOFlow extends Poly1{
  implicit val in = at[P]{ i => makeI(i) }
  implicit val out = at[R]{ r => makeO(r) }

  def makeI(p: P): I
}
```

and via transformation of your call to an HList, you will be able to map:

```
val input: I :: O :: I :: O :: I :: O = prprpr.map(IOFlow)
```

Comment: I need to provide implementation for `makeI(p: P): I` and `makeO(p: R): O`. From my understanding, this will mean that when I map the flow to `IOFlow`, it will transform my `Publish` to an `Input`, but at a value level. I would like to make this transformation at type level (`P#type -> I#type`).

Comment: @tase92 I don't believe you actually need to include the `Mapper` trait. That should happen automagically for you. If it does complain about a lack of one if you don't include it, make sure you have the correct imports.

Comment: @tase92 One more thing, if you do plan on keeping the `Mapper` in there, don't have a return type of `S`. Return instead `mapper.Out` as the return type.